# Is there any limit to review tasks?

Tags: support, review-queues, rate-limiting

Are there any limits to the number of reviews a single user can make (per review type and per total number of reviews) daily?

Comment: it's easy to hit the limit when this is set to 20 reviews a day :)

Comment: Then you need to ponder the reviews more carefully, go away have a coffee or something, live your life and then come back.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do 20 reviews per day (UTC time, measured from 00:00 UTC to 23:59 UTC) in each review queue.

If a review queue has over a 200 items this is raised to 40 reviews/day. 
The threshold used to be 1000 items, but [it was lowered to 200 in April 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/812149).

For more details, see [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Jeff Atwood, one of the founders of SO / SE, gave his thoughts on rate-limiting in his blog post *[Rate Limiting and Velocity Checking](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rate-limiting-and-velocity-checking/)*. The idea is to prevent abuse of the system, or at least limit the amount of damage that abusive users can do.