# 1, 2, 3...test. Let’s increase the number of reviews & close votes for science!

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts

For many, many years users have [asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes) and [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154965/increase-the-number-of-reviews-based-on-reputation) and [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274035/increasing-reviews-per-queue-incrementally-beyond-1000) for changes to the number of close votes and the number of reviews per day. There's been [a little bit of skepticism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes/285486#285486) as to the efficacy of such changes, but so far that's been mostly speculative. So... Let's test it!

### Current Problem:

We've got too many items staying the in Close Vote and the Low Quality queues for far too long before being handled. Over the past 30 days, we're averaging about 9,500 close vote and about 750 low quality reviews in the queue on a daily basis:

> [image: Review]

Close Vote reviewers currently get 40 reviews a day, the Low Quality reviewers get 20 a day, and a max of 50 close votes per day.

## What's Changing for the Test?

Over the next 30 days, we'll increase the number of reviews per day and max close votes to the following:

- When the queue size is less than 1000, the max reviews per day is 30
- When the queue size is 1000 or more, the max reviews per day is 60
- Maximum close votes = 60 to correspond to the new max reviews per day

### How will this change be evaluated?

At the end of the 30 days, we'll run the numbers again to see if these increases impact the average daily size of the queues. We are determining success the following way:

- If we see a **reduction in size by 20% of the close vote and low quality review queue**, then we will assume that this worked and we'll look at leaving the new thresholds in place permanently.
- If we don't hit a 20% reduction, then we will classify this as a failure.  The assumption being that the problem is not the number of votes or number of reviews.

While these increases will impact the other queues, we're really looking at reductions in both the Close Vote and Low Quality queues.

### How can you help

Pretend you didn't read this. We already have a lot of users reviewing, so keep doing what you are doing. This change doesn't mean you have to go and use all of your reviews per day, unless you really want to.  We expect most users will continue their normal behavior in review.

I'll be back in 30 days to report on the results...

Comment: [Comments archived.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/108433/discussion-on-question-by-bluefeet-1-2-3-test-lets-increase-the-number-of)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### Update (August 4, 2016)

We've updated the settings a bit:

- When the queue size is greater than 150, you will have 40 reviews a day
- When the queue size is less than 150, you will have 20 reviews a day

We also updated the settings in Triage to allow a maximum of 200 posts at a time. By increasing the number of posts allowed in Triage, it will allow the possibility of more posts to be reviewed by users each day.

---

### Update (April 26, 2016)

As mentioned in the initial answer, we were going to be working on a way to better scale the number of reviews available in the Low Quality review queue.

Effective immediately:

- When the queue size is greater than 200, you will have 40 reviews a day
- When the queue size is less than 200, you will have 20 reviews a day

This impacts all review queues but based on the average size of the queues, it will primarily impact the Low Quality queue.

---

The 30 days allotted to this test have come to an end, and the limits adjusted for this purpose have reverted to their normal values. Now, it's time to analyze the results and see what effects altering these limits had during the test period.

### Results: size of review queues

Increasing the number of reviews and close votes impacted the size of the review queues. Overall, both the Close Vote Review and Low Quality queues had a substantial drop in the average number of posts during the test period.

As a reminder, in order to say this was a success, we wanted a 20% decrease in the queue size. While we crushed that in the Low Quality review queue, we did not hit those numbers in the Close Vote queue.

> [image: 30 days later]

- The Close Votes had an **11% reduction** in queue size, dropping from 9,500 per day to 8,400 per day
- The Low Quality queue had a **74% reduction** in queue size, dropping from 750 per day to 192 per day

Over this period, we had 1,930 distinct users reviewing in both queues. But, very few of the reviewers capped out their reviews at least once during the test:

- 113 users maxed out their close vote reviews
- 405 users maxed out their low quality reviews

### Tangential results: automatic classification of low-quality answers

Based on [Brad's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319133/426671) , I looked at how accurately the system identifies answers that should be deleted before dumping them into review. Well, the short answer there is "not very accurately". An awful lot of stuff is being dumped into the queue that won't ever be deleted, and probably shouldn't be; this wastes reviewer time and prevents them from looking at things that've been flagged and thus stand a much, *much* higher chance of actually needing attention. We're going to tweak the settings to reduce the amount of noise generated by this system; we expect this alone to reduce the backlog by close to 20%.

### What's next?

We've stopped the test, meaning that you're back to 20 low quality reviews, 40 in close votes, and back to 50 max close votes for the day. But don't fret we're not going to stay here for long.

This test made us realize a few things:

1. More reviews in the low quality queue means more NAA/VLQ flags are processed out of the moderator flag queue quicker, helping with the backlog
2. We need to do something about the close votes, but having the same number of reviews and votes doesn't work well for users who want to review and close outside of review because they'll run out of votes.

We'll be tweaking the automated quality checks immediately (as noted above). Next, we'll work on building a way for the number of reviews available in the Low Quality queue to scale more effectively.

Then, we'll start looking at [increasing the number of close votes based on rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266500/proposal-to-make-close-votes-scale-with-rep).

Comment: -1 for turning back the number of Close votes, +2 for increasing the number of close votes based on rep. Thanks for running the experiment and the feedback.

Comment: I am curious.  Did more or less people max out CV reviews during the test the in the 30 days before the test.

Comment: @NathanOliver More people maxed out their CV reviews in the 30 days prior to the test. I grabbed the last 30 days when it was set to 40/day and were 150 users who hit the max at least once.

Comment: @bluefeet Thanks for the information.

Comment: less people maxing sounds realistic. I pick the [low hanging fruit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285534/839601) when in the queue, making it as easy as possible but even this way, even after getting used to new limit, it still felt noticeably harder than 40 reviews a day. I would say 60 reviews seems to be really approaching reviewer fatigue. You probably can stretch it a little bit more by "amplifying" current CV prioritisation heuristic (which works already well btw), but only a little bit

Comment: Yup @gnat those last 20 can be tough when you've already looked through a bunch of stuff that needs to be closed. Burn out can happen quickly in review.

Comment: "113 users maxed out their close vote reviews" how many maxed out their close *votes*? I know I didn't max out my reviews, but I did max out my votes.

Comment: @hichris123 108 users maxed out their close votes at least once during the test.

Comment: @bluefeet does that take into account a couple of mods that might have bothered on a couple of occasions to have a whack at the CV queue?

Comment: @JonClements I didn't exclude mods from these stats. Based on my quick once over, there weren't too many mods in the list.

Comment: All in all, I appreciate the 50% increase in the amount of reviews I could handle. Maybe a year from now I'll help out with those close votes.

Comment: Separate Close Votes from CVQ votes :-) Problem solved!

Comment: +1 for going back to 20 votes in LQ queue, maxed out every day except one at least.

Comment: this question was asked 28 days ago, how can that be 30 days, or did you start it before the post?

Comment: Interestingly, after an initial bump at the start fewer people hit >=40 votes/day during the last half of the test, @gnat. So yes: fatigue.

Comment: @Shog9 as I mentioned, one option to tame fatigue is to further amplify current ptioritisation, making even stronger push for insta-close items to the top of the queue. But 60 reviews would still be troublesome I'm afraid. Maybe 50

Comment: Not necessarily fatigue; I had to dial back on close vote review to make sure I had any close votes left while browsing the site itself.

Comment: @Yvette 30 days-ish, it ran for 4 weeks.

Comment: @bluefeet: How about accepting your own answer, so that the results can be found directly below the question?

Comment: @honk Done, just hadn't gotten back around to it.

Comment: @bluefeet: Hm, accepted self-answers don't go to the top? Didn't know that yet...

Comment: @bluefeet Even though CV queue didn't approach set parameters, having more votes increased number of questions closed. Also, I don't think that maxing out votes or not is significant, it is having ability to vote when you stumble upon horrible question that counts. From my experience during experiment, I would say that number of close votes we have in queue is sufficient, we should get more additional close votes to close questions outside queue. Fatigue is not relevant there. And it is extremely frustrating when you cannot close totally off topic question fast enough.

Comment: I agree with @gnat, there should be more priority given to posts with 4 close votes already. Perhaps there is an argument to make that this is giving bias towards robo reviewers since they are more likely to be accurate simply voting along the existing votes trajectory. However, I believe that once 4 votes are present the trajectory is more than likely accurate anyway especially given the low rate of reopen or edit after closure occurrences. As far as fatigue, I am not sure it will be a cure, but at least the effort will be instantly recognizable which plays into satisfaction levels.

Comment: "When the queue size is greater than 200, you will have 40 reviews a day" -- is this limited only to Stack Overflow? if it's network wide, how could there be 40 reviews at sites where users have only 24 close votes?

Comment: @gnat It's just Stack Overflow which is why this is posted on MSO.

Comment: I see, thanks. And there is no plan / intent to make it network wide, correct?

Comment: @gnat I don't think there is a need to make this network-wide at this time.

Comment: understood, thanks for explaining. As you wrote, primary purpose of this tweak is to accommodate dynamics of SO LQ queue

Comment: @gnat if there is proven need to do this elsewhere, we can.

Comment: I understand. You would just have to additionally examine and possibly adjust close vote limit if you would want to get it at some other site. 40 reviews in CV queue at a site with 24 votes would bring quite a bit of senseless Leave Opens from badge hunters

Comment: "Overall, both the Close Vote Review and Low Quality queues had a substantial drop in the average number of posts during the test period." The length of the close vote queue seem to kind of increase again after an initial two weeks low indicating a special effect by the announcement of this test. So my guess would be that the real effect on the close votes queue is less than 11% and giving a few more close votes to a few users with high rep might not change that, especially given that "very few of the reviewers capped out their reviews at least once during the test".

Comment: Is speeding up the  Low Quality queue review resulting in more items being put in the close queue?

Comment: Huh @IanRingrose, those queues are completely different. Questions don't go into the Low Quality queue.  I'm not sure I understand why you'd think low quality would impact the close queue.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: @bluefeet, Sorry I was thinking that the low quality queue got questions that the machine learning system decided were bad.

Comment: Ah ok @IanRingrose those questions go [Triage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage).

Comment: @bluefeet according to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330301/why-does-the-max-of-reviews-in-low-quality-posts-review-queue-bump-to-40-witho), you still get 40 reviews per day when the queue size is 200. This would imply the test is still going on?!

Comment: Hmm ... I might have misread the answer. The first section is apparently not part of the test-which-has-ended.

Comment: **About Update (August 4, 2016)** - What happens if I start reviewing when the queue is at 151? Do I keep 40 reviews for the whole day? Or as soon as the queue decreases under 150 I get back to 20? And what if the queue goes down when I'm at (e.g.) 27 reviews today?

Comment: If it worked, why remove it? When's this going to be back?

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC it didn't produce the results the exact results that we wanted so as a compromise we've made some adjustments to the total number is reviews users get on a daily basis based on queue size. We're continuing to discuss other things that we can do to fine tune the queues as mentioned last week we made additional changes.

Comment: @CliffBurton the number of reviews is based on queue size so if it starts off > 150 you'd have 40 reviews but it would drop to 20 if/when the queue size falls below 150.

Comment: @bluefeet maybe a bigger increase would be be better - we have proof it works at least somewhat

Comment: About this limit of 200 items in the Triage queue.. Is that still valid? Does it mean that if there are 200 items in the queue all other VLA-Questions get a free pass?

Answer (score 74):

As long as we're talking about testing and the Low Quality Posts review queue, can I suggest two more things to evaluate?

**The hit rate of system-heuristic-identified posts inserted into review.** The Low Quality Posts review queue used to be only fed by posts that were identified by a quality heuristic (poor capitalization, short length, etc.). Then SE started feeding posts into it that had been identified by "very low quality" flags, and finally ones with "not an answer" flags.

I'm no longer convinced that system-identified posts serve a useful purpose in this review queue. I'd like to know the percentage of system-identified "low quality" posts that did not receive a flag from a human and that were later deleted in review. When I did a manual review of this, I saw very little signal in these. If that percentage was low enough, I'd argue that we should no longer have the system identify these in order to focus the queue on more relevant items.

**Reducing the number of votes required to delete or dequeue a post from Low Quality Posts review.** I have been pleasantly surprised at how relatively problem-free reviews in this queue have been. At present, it takes quite a few reviews to delete a single non-answer or other post from review.

I believe that it would not harm the quality of review too greatly to examine reducing the number of votes required to delete an item or mark it as acceptable. Even reducing by a single vote might be enough to bring review closer to parity with the rate of incoming "not an answer" flags.

Increasing the number of reviews per person could help, but the above might also have a significant impact on the processing rate of the Low Quality Posts review queue.

Comment: This is a first test to see if we can make an impact in the queue. I'm not sure if we will make other tweaks with this test. I will say that I'm looking at a few other things, but we want to test one thing at a time.  However, I'll see about pulling some numbers of what's being fed into the low quality review queue.

Comment: To the second point, having users with the 20k rep to cast delete votes count for more than the 1/5 of the users necessary to delete the question would help.  If those delete votes, rather than recommend delete votes, counted for, say, double, that might help.

Comment: @bluefeet - Oh yeah, best to change one variable at a time. A few moderators were talking about this stuff yesterday, so I thought I'd toss these out as possible future items to look at.

Comment: @Servy that make a lot of sense.  Since 3 20k users can delete a bad answer outside the queue, and it takes 6 "Recommend deletion" votes within the queue, it seems pretty logical that delete votes within the queue count for 2 "Recommend deletion" votes (2/6 = 1/3).

Comment: If we aren't willing to ditch the heuristics entirely, can we at least prioritize the flagged posts (which a human has already judged to be a problem they organically found when browsing the site) over the heuristic-identified posts?  (In a separate experiment, of course.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom As I mentioned, I'm looking at a few different things... [patience you must have](http://melindascollins.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/patience-yoda-300x213.jpg).

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom Before we prioritize we should check if it is a problem at all. Maybe the heuristic is so strict that it identifies only positives (but not all of them). In that case maybe these should be prioritized and not ditched at all because it takes away work to identify them manually. First step is gathering data.

Comment: @Trilarion in my experience it's a friggin' problem in LQ queue, it breaks [the flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_%28psychology%29) and breaks it hard. This is especially noticeable when compared to CV queue which feeds me easiest items first. I wouldn't mind wasting my time, 20 (30) reviews a day isn't a big deal but the real harm is, as a result moderators get loaded by hundreds flags that could be handled by reviewers in a matter of minutes. I've seen blatant, textbook NAAs hanging in queue for _hours_ until they eventually reach moderators - this just doesn't feel right

Comment: Today in the VLQ I came across [a zero scored question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974791/polygon-triangulation) with four zero scored answers from 2009. Now anyone tell me that in the past everything was better on SO.

Comment: @bluefeet I can attest to this beeing the case heavily. About 50-60% of the posts I review in the LQP Queue are "Try this: $code". Those are answers. Either the heuristic is not very good or a ton of people are on a flagging spree.

Comment: @Magisch Flagging spree - bad flagging spree.

Comment: @bluefeet I feel horrible having to OK most of these posts, but answers are answers and them beeing bad doesn't make them delete worthy. Shouldn't people who go on bad flagging sprees get a flag timeout after so many declined ones?

Comment: @bluefeet - I have noticed that the heuristic does tend to throw a lot of "try this: (code)" answers into review, because it skews towards shorter answers. These were many of the ones that I saw when I swept through and started wondering about the hit rate of the system heuristics. That's not to say that there aren't some people out there who blindly flag any answer with "try this" in it, but the system does seem to contribute more than a few of these.

Comment: For example, these are all posts that were inserted into review by the heuristic this morning: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11669804 http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11668147 http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11669673 http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11669865 and they all follow the "try this" pattern of answer. None are worth the time to review for deletion.

Comment: So the heuristics is wrong and produces more work instead of less? A good example for the importance of regularly monitoring the false positive rates of heuristics.

Comment: @Magisch I Skip these but this works [worse than usual](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232140/165773). First, because I'm afraid to miss something really worthy of deletion, like plagiarism and second, (likely most important) because these are mixed so randomly with straightforward garbage. Yet again, CV queue works so much smoother, it starts by giving me very easy items and gradually gets harder later so I can predict the load and manage my effort

Comment: @gnat I review [tag:c] and [tag:sql] CVs daily. They tend to be ~60% "I instantly close this", ~10% merits closer examination and ~30% Skip or leave open.

Comment: @Magisch 60% insta-close is just the magic of system prioritizing CV queue ([explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/165773)). If we had something like that in LQ, life would be so much easier for everyone (human flags and items with larger amount of already performed reviews get higher priority, it's not a rocket science)

Comment: @Servy: I assume you mean prorate the delvotes, so a single delvote counts for two and two delvotes for four? Because 3 delvotes will already finish the review (whether cast in or out of the queue), as I expect you know.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Sure, or just count a "suggest delete" vote as half a real delete vote, but yes, I was aware that 3 delete votes on an answer would deleted it, and I'm also aware that that virtually never happens.

Comment: @Servy: I have an idea I don't think I've posted yet for using sorting to clump heavily delvoted reviews toward 20kers and heavily recommended reviews toward others, such that as few review actions of opposing type as possible are spent on a task dominated by a given type. I think that would be a bit safer than letting 2k review actions count as full, non-expiring downvotes. Prorating delvotes would be fairly harmless, though, by comparison.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That seems like way more work, for, at best, the same benefit.

Comment: Regarding the accuracy of the automated heuristics... Might wanna have a separate thread for that, since posting data in comments is not going to work terribly well.

Answer (score 48):

Alright, well, shoot. Whether it’s [reverse psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_psychology), the [Hawthorne effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawthorne_effect), or some other fun social phenomenon, I am only human, and I am too curious for my own good. So why not? I decided to go back into the review queues after being thoroughly discouraged since [my initial post on the subject](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285438/465378) and see what happened.

First of all, **yay. Thank you.** It is nice to know that my request was heard, if perhaps a year late. Having more close votes sure does feel different, and it’s actually pretty nice. Unfortunately, this implementation actually kinda missed the point of my original post.

> I'm not really complaining about a failure to close all the questions. That won't ever really be fixed. But frankly, I want to be able to close questions that I deem poor. When I run out of close votes, **I stop trying to answer questions in poor-quality tags because I'm frustrated I can't close the awful ones.** This actually reduces my positive contributions to the site, and I don't imagine I'm alone in that.

## It’s not about the review queues

When I posted my initial request for more close votes, I scraped together a [scary graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/270916/number-of-unclosed-questions-with-close-votes-per-month#graph) displaying the number of unclosed questions per month:

[image]

This graph shows a symptom—questions getting some close votes but never enough to seal the deal—a symptom that the close vote queue is pretty much explicitly designed to fix. With that in mind, it might seem like this issue is really about the review queues. **It isn’t.**

Here’s what that graph looks like today, in March 2016:

[image]

***What happened?*** Well, [Shog happened](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/188673). New close vote aging logic was implemented to age out close votes that weren’t getting enough attention, replacing [the old logic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166124/188673) which let them stick around. With this in place, [the effects were sudden, and the effects were total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBJ1v.png). The review queues were no longer a problem.

### Reviewing posts is a chore

So, let me be honest: I do not like going through the review queues. I haven’t been doing it much lately, but that is not because things have changed, I’ve just been a lot busier. That’s not the point. I don’t know if anyone actually *enjoys* clicking through posts in the queue (almost all of which are terrible), but I don’t, and I would expect I am not alone in that feeling.

So then why would I use the queues? Why *do I* use the queues? Well, there are some motivators:

- **Stinkin’ badges.** I already have both the close vote queue badges, so this is less relevant to me, but some good gamification can’t ever really hurt, especially just to get things going. (Generally, though, I think the motivation factor of these badges is overstated.)
- **Small, easy goals.** The review queues are generally nearly instant gratification. Just take a few minutes out of your day, and boom. Twenty posts reviewed. This is an easy goal to work towards—it isn’t hard, but it feels good to have finished it.
- **Feeling like you’ve done your part.** Related to the above, getting that “come back tomorrow” screen feels good. It says “I did my part for today”, and that’s it. I can feel a little tiny bit better about myself, and I can get on with my life.

Those last two points are especially important because they create a positive feedback loop to produce a self-sustaining system. First, the goal feels achievable, so I’m willing to invest some time to just knock out the queue. Second, I get a feeling of gratification when I’m done. This makes me want to do more, which I can do consistently because it is so easy to do each day. Et cetera.

This balance is delicate, and it almost certainly isn’t the same for everyone, but erring on the side of caution is important to maintain that positive loop because...

### [Protecting people from themselves](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285473/465378)

...queue burnout is a real thing that happens. I just ran through the queue and reviewed sixty—that’s right, ***sixty!***—posts. That is a big number. And you know what? I’m not sure I would want to come back and do it tomorrow, even though I might if it were a paltry forty. Now, one might point out that I could just do twenty and call it a day, but that’s not what my brain’s reward centers crave: I want that positive reinforcement, dammit! So I am possibly doing even *less* by being given the option to do *more*.

So with that in mind, was Shog right and was I wrong? Was increasing the cap a bad idea with potentially disastrous consequences? Well... I still don’t think so. It isn’t quite that simple.

## It was never about the queues, anyway

Let me select some quotes from my question and its associated comments. First, that original quote once again, from me:

> When I run out of close votes, **I stop trying to answer questions in poor-quality tags because I'm frustrated I can't close the awful ones.**

From [Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18157/jim-garrison):

> After I run out I see no point in slogging through the muck looking for the occasional gem if I can't help clean up the muck. I really believe in StackOverflow as a resource and I'm not here for the rep. The vote limits are contribution limits.

From [Josh Caswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/603977/josh-caswell):

> For myself, I know that I only hit the cap when I use /review -- and (paradoxically?) that's **part of the reason** I don't use /review much. Burning through the queues -- and thus my votes -- doesn't take all that much time compared to the rest of the normal browsing day. Sure, I could stop reviewing early, and save myself more votes depending on the time, but then I'm putting way too much strategic thought into, as Will likes to say, mopping up the sick on the floor. (And I'm not even sure there's a displayed counter of daily close votes.)

From [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist):

> Despite being the top CV reviewer there, I "seldom" use the CV queue on ELU because then I run out right away. Yes, I get a few more but I still run out of CVs there on most days I'm an active voter. I bet if you look at the site stats, you'll see this isn't rare. I try to treasure them up and look for canidates in the 10k queue as need be. Just too many need closing to squander my CVs, which means I don't use them enough as much as I should.

The people who are hitting the caps and getting frustrated **don’t want more time in the trash compactor**, they want **the privilege to throw the litter they find in the trash**.

The people who spend time in the queues are on cleanup duty, but they are really a necessary evil. Ideally, we wouldn’t need to waste valuable human resources on validating close votes. If all close votes were cast intelligently and fairly, the close vote queue would be pointless—but we’d still need the initial person to cast that first vote. Ultimately, this is where the frustration seems to happen the most.

### Close votes are a panic button

In Stack Overflow’s most popular tags, there is an extremely low signal to noise ratio, and the “close” button is a way out. It’s a way of saying “eep, this question is not worth my time *or anyone else’s*, please get it out of my face!” (Or for you power users, it’s pronounced <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>.)

The close vote is comforting to the user searching to answer good questions because it marks that question as adequately managed and has signaled to the system that it is of low quality. Theoretically, this system (along with ordinary up/downvotes) helps good questions rise to the top as the sand sinks to the bottom. Whether or not this is actually true in practice is mostly irrelevant to this particular post; the point is simple: being unable to report poor questions causes a surprising amount of psychological friction on the part of the benevolent user. **The barrier is *not* being unable to close all the questions, it is being deprived of the way out: the panic button.**

### What does all this have to do with this question, again?

Alright, so the issue is that people ran out of close votes, and we increased the number of close votes people have. Alright! Good work, team. But wait, no, we tried to solve a problem but instead we made two problems:

1. Going through the close vote queue is more of a chore than it used to be.
2. After going through the queue, I am *still* out of close votes, and this makes me more likely to stop sifting through crap.

Well, fortunately for us, [Shog has an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes#comment152206_285486):

> Also, I recommend not reviewing until you're about done for the day - I used to leave that sort of thing for about 23:00 UTC.

Of course, [that’s not really a perfect solution, either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285438/we-need-more-close-votes#comment152316_285486):

> Not reviewing until the end of the day, dose not work well for people in different time zones. I think part of the problem is that the RISK of running out of close vote is putting people off form reviewing a lot, even when most of them do not run out of close votes.

(Plus, it interacts poorly with the psychological gamification tricks mentioned earlier.)

What am I arguing then? Well, my opinion isn’t really anything new—[Félix Gagnon-Grenier’s answer to this very same question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319156/465378) already makes my point for me!

> **TL;DR;** We should still have more close votes than reviews.

[Josh Caswell had a slightly different solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285473/465378), but the spirit was the same:

> **Votes of any kind** in each queue should be **limited only** by the queue's **daily task limit**; they should not be deducted from one's pool of that kind of vote.

**Yes**, this is something of a different conclusion from my post a year ago, and **yes**, this is a bit of a cynical view of the problem. However, I think the stats don’t lie—no matter how the queue is doing now, those questions clearly aren’t so awful that they are truly in need of closing, given that the votes just age away, anyway.

I think it is worth acknowledging that this is not really a technical problem but a **social and psychological one**, and understanding our (sometimes irrational!) frustrations is important to understanding what exactly the solution needs to be.

Thank you for taking the time to consider these issues, thank you for being willing to hear our feedback, and a *big thank you* for reading all this and taking it into consideration. It is well-appreciated. And who knows? Maybe it’s time for me to get a little more involved again.

Comment: "The people who are hitting the caps and getting frustrated don’t want more time in the trash compactor, they want the privilege to throw the litter they find in the trash." - perhaps a more "powerful" close vote (similar to the dupehammer) would be beneficial here? It seems a large part of the problem is questions languish for days until 5 close votes can be obtained.

Comment: This matches my experience: Hawthorne effect drew me in, 60 reviews is a total slog, and then afterward I elected not to close a question because I didn't want to "waste" one of my four remaining votes.  In contrast, I really enjoyed having extra LQP reviews: I cleaned up more crap in the queue _and_ I felt better flagging crap when I came across it later because I knew it would be cleaned up soon after.

Comment: The fact that we have exactly as many CVs and reviews artificially lessens the queue, but only because people reviewing properly in it no longer have the votes to push more qs into it.

Comment: Whats additionally problematic to this change is that while reviewing 60 CVs a day, you have not enough vote left to properly review triage / FP posts. You end up skipping more then half or beeing artificially lenient, and both of those are bad.

Comment: So... This is an experiment. Critically, it's an experiment we can run without changing any of the logic that governs close votes, which is nice because honestly I doubt we'd do it otherwise. 50 close votes is rather a lot of close votes; I've been saying this for years, but there are very few people who can tolerate looking at that many crap questions in a day and still have the energy to pick a useful close reason for each one. It's a slog, and it doesn't much matter how you approach it. And that's fine... As long as your vote means something when you DO vote. Which is where review comes in.

Comment: @Shog9 I think you may have missed the point, which is actually probably my fault for not making it clear enough. Let’s make it clear this time: **I simply think the number of close votes should be increased to 60, but the CV reviews per day should remain capped at 40.** That doesn’t require changing any of the logic (at least I would hope it doesn’t), and it accomplishes my goal.

Comment: I don't actually see how that wouldn't make the problem you're describing *worse*, @Alexis.

Comment: @Shog9 [Link to our relevant discussion in chat for context.](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/close-vote-woes)

Answer (score 32):

**TL;DR;** We should still have more close votes than reviews.

---

I would like to discuss an aspect of this which may have an impact on the results, which is the total quantity of close-votes being tied to the max number of close votes reviews

> Maximum close votes = 60 to correspond to the new max reviews per day

This at first sight seems pretty logical, but I really wonder if it won't have an unforeseen effect.

Egotistically, I'll just think about my experience: I often (relatively, I have not been in the 3k group for a long time) cast close votes from using the site. This did not have an effect before because, even if I used a few close votes, I still had enough to actually handle 40 reviews.

However, being able do 60 reviews, I still cast close votes from outside the review queue with my close votes limited at 60.

So, effectively, having 60 reviews per day won't actually do anything about the close votes review queue. I'll still handle the exact same number of close votes reviews per day, except I will never reach the limit of reviews per day.

**Can we have 80 close votes per day, please?**

That is, at least for the purpose of the test, because I think that would affect the results.

Comment: Yeah, this setup kind-of encourages me to wait to go through the review queue until shortly before UTC time roles around, even more so than before.

Comment: they could at the very least [give extra CVs to bronze / silver tag badge holders](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240702/165773) in their tags

Comment: See my [similar request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268477/245360) on MSE. It proposed to split the votes between review queue and regular view. It will make users use those votes in the right way.

Comment: I don't think we'll be making any additional changes during this test. The purpose of this is to see how these tweaks impact the size of the review queues. Giving more close votes without additional close reviews could potentially offset some of the work in the review queue as users would have 20 more votes to put more stuff in review.

Comment: Yeah, I talked about this in one of the previous discussions of increasing close votes, but if folks are less pressured to prioritize voting that can easily make the backlog *much worse*. There are, of course, complicated ways of avoiding that... But the whole point of this test is to see if it's even worth putting more thought into.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking... you're saying we have more reviews available but also more close votes so the overall balance will stay the same? Or are you saying something else?

Comment: *"Can we have 80 close votes per day, please?"* - Lordie, what with the ever increasing amount of *bad* and/or *poorly written* questions these days, that would be a reasonable amount, if not "100". Many a time, I have to take it easy as to the amount of votes to close I put in, or used to put in. Newbies (and some who have been around for a while), tend to post questions with a lot of the missing essential parts they deem as being irrelevant. *Well, well, well....*, we read code and not minds. They just take off and expect a *magic* answer. Sometimes it happens, other times it goes stale.

Comment: @TylerH Yep, that is *partly* what I am saying. We have (for the duration of the test) more reviews, but not more close votes. Which means that the overall balance will *not* stay the same. If the close votes/reviews ratio stayed the same but was augmented by 20, then the overall balance would stay the same while favoring more reviews being made.