# How many self-answers get deleted, and how?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, self-answer, statistics

Good self-answers can be some of the most valuable posts on the site, but many self-answers are deleted in the Low Quality Posts review queue because they should have been edits to the question or comments on another answer.  I'd like to know:

- What fraction of self-answers get deleted?
- By what mechanism do the self-answers get deleted (LQP, delete votes, binding author vote, question was deleted, more that I can't think of)?
- How do these stats depend on the duration between asking and answering?  (For example, I hypothesize that self-answers posted within an hour of the question being asked are more likely to be deleted than either instant-self-answers or later self-answers.)

(These questions were inspired by the recent [admission that the LQP heuristics should be improved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/3614835), and a personal proto-project to write some NAA-detection regexes for SmokeDetector.)