# Changing max number of reviews

Tags: discussion, review-queues

Can anyone clarify it for me? I'm only 1k rep so can't see max reviews per day in close votes and low quality but: there was increasing of maximum reviews in all other queues (triage, first post etc.) for previous days (up to 30 instead of 20) but today it's 20 again. I found this question [1,2,3...test](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science) but here is no any information about changing max reviews of other queues except of increasing.

So my question is: why today number of reviews in Triage et.al. is 20 instead of 30?
Is it due to the fact something like this:

> When the queue size is less than 1000, the max reviews per day is 30

P.S. Tried to post it like comment in this question, but it is too long.

Comment: Have a look here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/559745 The limit has been reverted to 20.

Comment: @Floern ahh yes, I see it now. I made mistake because question was posted at 16 of March and now just 14 of April. So I thought it'll end later.