# Has the amount of Low Quality review slots been increased?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I've noticed that several people, including myself, have been able to do 40 Low Quality reviews today. Instead of the usual 20.

This is normal if the size of the queue exceeds 1000 items, but that was not the case. I opened a separate browser, where I was not logged in, and the number of reviews never got above 300.

Also, I don't see the majority of my reviews in my review history; this would make sense for posts that have been deleted since reviewing, but I do see some of them in my comment history - posts that I reviewed, are still alive, but don't show up in the review history.

So - is SO perhaps changing things in the Low Quality queue, as a result of the [recent experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science)? When we temporarily got more Close Vote reviews and Low Quality reviews?

Comment: [Yes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/4342498)

Comment: If you see my answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science/320971#320971) you'll notice the change.