# Difference between "stats" vs "review" review count shows for Review|Low Quality Posts

Tags: bug, review-queues

Total Low Quality Posts Review count for the day is different on two different page. See the screenshot. One says, I completed 20 review while second says 30.

[image]

And

[image]

Comment: I think the "Thank you..." bit just displays whatever the current limit is.

Comment: But when you complete 40 reviews for the day in LQP, then it shows "Thank you for reviewing 40..."

Comment: I was just noticing that myself,  but it's 25 for me.

Comment: related: [1, 2, 3…test. Let’s increase the number of reviews & close votes for science!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/839601) "we were going to be working on a way to better scale the number of reviews available in the Low Quality review queue.

Effective immediately:

    When the queue size is greater than 200, you will have 40 reviews a day..."

Comment: 10220 LQ reviews, 46145 reviews in total... Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

My guess is that when you started reviewing, the queue size was a little more than 200, so the limit was 40. After you reviewed 30 posts, the size got below 200, so the limit got back to 20. That's why it shows "Thank you for reviewing 20 low quality posts", while you reviewed 30.

I don't think this bug is worth fixing.

Edit: I don't know if something has changed, but today I started reviewing when the queue size was 204, and I reviewed 40 posts.

Comment: Does the posts someone review themselves change how many they can review.   E.g. if the queue was 230 posts...

Comment: @IanRingrose I don't know if that's a question, but if there are 230 items in the queue, and someone review 30 of them, then that person see that there are 200 items in the queue.

Comment: So the person may get told they can't review any items until the next day, a few more items are added to the queue, and then they are allowed to review items.