# "Close Votes" queue is overun

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I recently got to 500+ reputation and as an active member of SO I wanted to help by reviewing. I couldnt help it noticing that only the **"close votes"** section has more than **8,500 requests** on the queue. I see that as a potential problem for SO because some of these would take too much time to get processed. And as long as it takes time for people to reach 3,000+ reputation I dont see a permanent solution comign up soon.

I just thought of a temporary solution that I would like to share with you.

<del>My proposition is to **lower** the current 3,000+ needed reputation to vote on "close votes" to 1,000 (were much more users have 1,000+ reputation) for a **limited time only** so they can help clearing the queue.</del>

If that would happen it would give enough time to the 3,000+ reputation users after the time passes to clearing on their own the "close votes" queue without any problem.

---

**UPDATE**

After i read *Magisch's* answer I realised he had a point. I still see it as a "problem" though, because flags are being made for a reason, some of them not being proccesed and getting timed out shouldnt be allowed.

And in continue to that and based on his answer I would like to counter propose the following:

The currently allowed users (3,000+ reputation), would have their limit of reviewing (for the "close votes" queue only) doubled for a period of time which we could call "test period". If during that period the moderators see that tis is working better than the previous state then I would suggest keeping it or else discarding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The close vote queue has been filled up to one degree or another for quite a while now.

Closing questions is a privilege we only entrust to users that have shown a decent amount of committment to the site. I don't think changing the reputation requirement is a good idea.

> My proposition is to lower the current 3,000+ needed reputation to
>   vote on "close votes" to 1,000 (were much more users have 1,000+
>   reputation) for a limited time only so they can help clearing the
>   queue.

You assume this queue is "one time full", but its not. If it was empty tomorrow it'd be back at a large number in a week or two. Close votes and flags age away out of the queue every day, and more questions come in every day, which is why its been hovering between 7-11k for as long as I can remember here.

Comment: thanks for the answer, please read the updated question and tell me what you think of that... thanks in advance

Comment: @hedgehog That was attempted and concluded a failure before. [Link to it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science)

Comment: i am very sorry then..... though i really think that would solve the problem, but as long as it was actually tested and found not good, not more to do i guess....