# How many posts can a user review per day?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, review-queues

I read and observed that a user can review a maximum of 20 posts of a category. **But** today I noticed a strange thing that some user could review 40 posts. How is it possible?

For proof, check this image:

[image]

Is it a bug or new limits for review?

When I reached 27 reviews, I was not be able to view more. But others reviewed 40 posts.

Comment: The limit is increased for certain queues under specific conditions. More info [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971)