# What is the maximum amount of triage reviews per day?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

Up until now when I've reviewed Triage, the number of reviews per day was limited to 20, and once I reviewed 20 posts I couldn't review more. But today I first reviewed 20 triage posts and then as usual it stopped me from reviewing more posts. But after having reviewed First Posts, the same day, I came back and it let me review 20 more posts so that I reviewed 40 posts today, saying "Thank you for reviewing 40 triage questions". Why is this? Is it a bug or did I gain the privilege to review more posts? How is the maximum amount of triage reviews per day calculated?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/2675154