# I am only able to review 20 Low Quality Posts. What happened?

Tags: support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I generally try to review 40 low quality posts per day, as I enjoy helping out on SO. However, when I reviewed the low quality posts today, the limit that I hit was 20 posts instead of 40. It doesn't seem to me that I failed an audit as I'm rather meticulous on the whole while reviewing questions. Additionally, other users have reviewed 40 LQPs today, so I was wondering if there was a way that my limit was reduced somehow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For all of the review queues, the cap is based on the size of the queue. If there are more than 150 tasks in the queue (or there were a few minutes ago), then you will be capped at 40 reviews, otherwise 20. The size of LQP dropped below 150, so you were only able to review 20 tasks.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320971/6392939