# Make it possible to approve/reject more edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rate-limiting

I know, you're going to think me strange, but I find the process of approving and rejecting edits strangely appealing. Can we have more on a daily basis than the basic 20?

*(Not sure if this is a feature request as such, but added the flag anyway).*

Comment: I'm half expecting someone to edit my question.....!

Comment: We want to avoid robo reviewers pressing the same button dozens and dozens of times withough thought or hindrance. Rate limiting is one weapon in that fight.

Comment: You do use Skip, I suppose? It's always OK to Skip a review, and you can Skip as many as you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson: I suppose, though I do tend to pay attention (though I will freely admit that my mind can be on other things!).

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Skip's for pussies! ... *<Miaow>*!

Comment: @Paul Must... not... bark....   must... not... bark... :-)

Comment: So you could say that my question [is technically a duplicate (see the link)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341174/1945782). If anyone wants to flag it then I could put it in the close queue!!

Comment: See! @CodyGray edited my question! ;o)

Comment: What we really need are more people reviewing questions in the *vote to close* queue. It currently contains ~7,000 questions. The suggested edit queue rarely contains more than 200. You are almost able to help us where we really need it, only 15 more answer upvotes to go!

Comment: @CodyGray: I know. I've just been lazy recently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 20 reviews per day, unless the queue exceeds 150 items; then you get 40.

Like almost everything on Stack Exchange, it is rate-limited. As Robert Longson pointed out in [their comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270418/168333) on your question, this is one way to stop the damage done by robo-reviewers. We have many reviewers who blindly Approve anything. The rate limit stops them from doing more harm than they already are.

So, you might get 40 reviews on some days, but you won't get more.

There is an exception though: if someone suggests edits to one of *your* posts, you can always Approve or Reject them. Even if you've already done 40 reviews that day.

Comment: I see. So what we need is to get more people to edit questions so I can get a bigger, better fix? :o)

Comment: @Paul Yes - or get them to edit answers :-)  Just encourage them to make _good_ edits! Seriously, you could also try to get past 5000 points. Then tag wiki edits will be added to the things you can review. Also, you're close to 3000 points, which opens the Close Votes review queue. We can always use good Close Vote reviewers.

Answer (score 2):

There has been some testing on this issue to check what would happen if the review queues limit was increased.

But it was found out that very few users maxed out their review limit, particularly for LQP and Close Votes.

> - 113 users maxed out their close vote reviews
> - 405 users maxed out their low quality reviews

For now you get up to 40 reviews if the review queue exceeds, which mostly happens with Triage, LQP and Close Votes.

Citing from [1, 2, 3...test. Let’s increase the number of reviews & close votes for science!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science/320971#320971)

Comment: Also often happens on Help & Improvement.

Comment: I'm not so hot for the quality questions and will have to earn that final 150 rep for the close votes! Nice stats, though. Interesting stuff.

Comment: I hope you gain 150 rep early as possible :)