# How are the hours limits for review queues calculated?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

When we reach the limit to review Questions/Answers in particluar review queue we can see

> Thank you for reviewing 20 triage questions; come back in **x** hours to
>   continue reviewing.

I see that x value tends to change. Sometimes I see that I can continue reviewing after 6 hours, 12 hours, 14 hours. So my question is

- value is calculated based on my reviews on post
- pass/fail audits
- or it's a random

This is a snippet of today after completing the Triage Reviews 
[image]

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170005/what-is-the-actual-time-limit-between-refresh-of-reviews

Comment: The first sentence on [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270518/2675154) also explains it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any limit to review tasks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270515/is-there-any-limit-to-review-tasks)

Comment: It's based on UTC. As you're in India, this means the limit resets at 5:30 AM local.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> - value is calculated based on my reviews on post

No

> - pass/fail audits

Nope

> - or it's a random

Certainly not.

The maximum amount of reviews allowed per day per user is per Stack Exchange day ([SE Day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start)). An SE Day starts at 0:00 UTC.

Once you exhausted the number of review task for that queue, the system calculates the time left between the UTC time of your last review and 23:59:59 UTC. The time you have to wait varies because you're not as consistent at which time you complete your daily review tasks.

Comment: Clicking the achievements button also shows the current UTC time